# Using Ribbon as LoadBalancer in Microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I am new to microservices.I have developed a stock application as per below structure::

- stock-ui [ui application using vaadin]
- stock-dbservice[microservicefor db calls]
- stock-serviceregistry[using eureka server as a discovery server]
- stock-apigateway[api gateway using zuul].

  ui-app-> api gateway->db service

I am using `RestTemplate` for service calls.Now I want to make it load balanced like below :

```
@LoadBalanced
@Bean
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

Now,I have couple of question here:

Do I need to explicitly mark it with `@LoadBalanced`?

Since,I am using Eureka as service registry so,eureka internally performs the LoadBalancing or I have to do it using Ribbon?